# Give 2 nested list and count the element in the innermost one

Tags: python

if I have 2 lists like:

**Subjects and credit:**

```
[['Math',6],['English',3],['Drama',2]]
```

**Students and scores:**

```
[['Amy',,90,80],['Jack','60','30','50'],['Tom','80','','50']]
```

and want to calculate them like this:

for Amy, there is no score in math. 90 in English(3 credits) and 80 in Drama(2 credits)
so it will output

```
[['Amy',,270,160],['Jack',360,90,100],['Tom'480,,100]]
```

**Edit:**

I solved it by myself. I just need to use things like

```
a[i][j] = b[i][j] *c [i][1]
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried to solve this problem so we can address the specific issues

Comment: In fact I have no idea about how to solve that problem right now.... maybe make two Triple nested list? But it seems not good. Is it the only way to solve that problem?

Comment: Your second list is syntax wise incorrect. Better would be to simply put `0` for a missing score

Comment: @How to delete the question: you can't delete a question while it has at least one answer with at least one upvote -> *You can't* ... You could ask André to delete his answer though... or ... hypothetically speaking... you could edit your question to violate the code of conduct and then flag it

Comment: OK...others spend time to answer me before I refresh it. If I delete it he may lost the upvote， so just keep it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
credit = [['Math',6],['English',3],['Drama',2]]
scores = [['Amy',None,90,80],['Jack',60,30,50],['Tom',80,None,50]]
output = [
    [stud[0]] +
    [
        None if score is None else score * credit[idx][1]
        for idx, score in enumerate(stud[1:])
    ] for stud in scores
]

print(output)

# [['Amy', None, 270, 160], ['Jack', 360, 90, 100], ['Tom', 480, None, 100]]
```

That said, you should probably implement this simpler, without list comprehension.

Comment: Nice one. The most pythonic way possible, I guess

Comment: @rjmessibarca Yeah, maybe, but not the most readable I suppose. :)

Comment: Thank you...Although I solved it by myself QAQ It is easy for me but I suddenly possessed by the devil =.=||||

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with student and score then you may want to use dictionaries or objects instead of lists. For example:

```
from typing import List

class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
        self.subjects_ = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def add_subject(self, subject_, score_: int):
        subject = Subject(subject_, score_)
        self.subjects_.append(subject)
        print(f"added {subject_} to {self.name} with a score of {score_}")

    def remove_subject(self, subject_):
        self.subjects_.remove(subject_)

    def subjects(self):
        return [s.name for s in self.subjects_]`

class Subject(object):
    def __init__(self, name: str, credits: int):
        self.name = name
        self.credits = credits
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

students = ['Amy', 'Jack', 'Tom']
math = Subject('math', 4)
history = Subject('history', 8)

amy = Student(students[0])
amy.add_subject(math,10)
amy.add_subject(history,6)

print(amy.subjects())
```